Entra AD login not working in Blazor WASM standalone Docker app
I have a monorepo with several projects, including a .NET web API and a Blazor WASM standalone project. The project structure is as follows:
root
  docker-compose.yaml
  | packages
     | api
        files
     | blazor
        blazor.sln
        | Client
           Client.csproj
           Dockerfile
           nginx.conf

docker-compose.yaml:
version: "3.7"

services:
  blazor:
    build:
      context: ./packages/blazor/Client
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ApiSettings__BaseUrl=http://localhost:8081
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  api:
    build:
      context: ./packages/api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
      - "8082:443"
    expose:
      - "80"

Dockerfile for Blazor app:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY Client.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore Client.csproj
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build Client.csproj -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish Client.csproj -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM nginx:alpine AS final
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=publish /app/publish/wwwroot .
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

And finally nginx.conf:
events { }
http {
   include mime.types;
   types {
      application/wasm;
    }
  server {
     listen 80;
     index index.html;
     location / {
        root /user/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
     }
  }
}

The blazor app is configured to use Entra AD to login users in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(builder.Configuration["ApiSettings:Scope"]!);
});

When running the API via docker-compose and the Blazor app directly from Rider, everything works smoothly. I have a login button which opens a standard login modal where the user enters their Microsoft credentials and logs in. However when I start both the API and the Blazor app via docker-compose as specified in the files above, nothing happens when I click the login button. The apps starts as they should, and the Blazor app opens on localhost:8080, but when I click the login button it seems like the login modal pops up for a millisecond and then nothing else happens. The console prints the following error, which I'm not sure if is relevant:
Source map error: Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Resource URL: http://localhost:8080/_framework/dotnet.runtime.8.0.4.riehddozk1.js
Source Map URL: dotnet.runtime.js.map

This error is not present when starting the app directly from Rider.
